# CSS nth-child expression to remove margin-bottom of last row

Tags: html, css, margin, css-selectors

I am creating lists that display in columns of two, every `.customer-review-container` has a margin-bottom like so:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">

    </div>  <!-- end customer-review-container -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">

    </div>  <!-- end customer-review-container -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">

    </div>  <!-- end customer-review-container -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">

    </div>  <!-- end customer-review-container -->
</div>
```

What I wish to do is create an nth-child expression to remove the `margin-bottom` of  on the last row (3rd and 4th), so I try with the code:

```
div:nth-child(3n+1).customer-review-container{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

But it only removes the margin-bottom of last div (4th).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
.col-md-6:nth-last-child(-n+2) .customer-review-container {
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**[Sample DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/53mvh9t2/)**

Comment: Now I have problem when it become responsive, it doesn't work properly. Please advice me about responsive display.

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-child(3n+1).customer-review-container, div:nth-child(3n+0).customer-review-container{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
div:nth-child(n+3) .customer-review-container{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

`:nth-child(n+3)` will target every div with an index superior or equal to 3 (indexes stars to 1).

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to target the last row, whatever if there's one **or** two elements, use this selector:

```
div:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(odd) > .customer-review-container,
div:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(odd) + div > .customer-review-container {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.customer-review-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(odd) > .customer-review-container,
div:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(odd) + div > .customer-review-container {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="customer-review-container">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. But if I have more 4 columns, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ow ok, you want to target the two last?

Comment: @TheHung I added the wanted seletor, to target the elements on the last line only (**even if there's 5/7/9... elements**)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `nth-last-child(n)` selector like so:

```
.customer-review-container:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

this will select the last two children